# Rsync from server to server without downloading locally

Tags: php, wordpress, shell, rsync

I am writing a script in shell for a Wordpress website, which takes the plugins, themes and uploads and puts them on a backup-website where I usually test and break stuff.

To make it easier for me to always have the latest version on the development website, I am running this script so that I don't have to manually import export everything, everytime.

At the moment I am running:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh -t ${HOST_REMOTE}:${PATH_REMOTE}/plugins/ ./plugins/
rsync -avzhe ssh ./plugins/ ${HOST_TARGET}:${PATH_TARGET}/plugins/
```

I am wondering if there is any way I could re-write this so that it could download the files from the remote directly to the target, without having to download them locally anymore.

Thank you very much for any input relevant to the subject.